# Error communicating with GSM SIM900 with AVR.?

Tags: avr, c, gsm, sim900

I am trying to interface GSM SIM900 with AVR Controller. Till now I have 
done programming which transmit the command ATD and it makes a
call to my cell. GSM response to this command by sending OK. I want to
make a program which also receives this response OK and to do that I have 
written my code but it is not working as it should be. I am attaching my
code please tell me where I am doing wrong.

CODE:

```
void serial_Init()
{
    UCSRB = (1<<TXEN)|(1<<RXEN);
    UCSRC = (1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<URSEL);
    UBRRL = 51;
}

void serial_Tx(char *str)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0;str[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        UDR=str[i];
        while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE)));
    }
}

 char serial_Rx()
 {
    //Wait untill a data is available

    while(!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)))
    {
         //Do nothing
    }

     //Now USART has got data from host
    //and is available is buffer

    return UDR;
 }

 void uart_put(char data)
 {
     UDR=data;
     while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE)));
 }

int main(void)
{
    DDRA = 0x00;
    DDRC = 0xFF;
    PORTA = 0xFF;
    serial_Init();
    char data[2];
    while(1)
    {
        if(PINA==0xFE)
        {
            serial_Tx("ATD<number>;\r\n");
            for(int j=0;j<=100;j++)
            {
                data[j] = serial_Rx();
                uart_put(data[j]);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Upate** Current result on hyperterminal:

[image]

Comment: You always place the received character at the end of your char array: `data[10] = serial_Rx(UDR);`. So the next received character will overwrite the previous, and the first nine chars will always be empty/memory garbage. Also `serial_RX()` has no parameters but you passed UDR to it in the main.

Comment: @BenceKaulics the char I am receiving also need to be displayed at hyper terminal that's why I am receving it and the storing it in data and then transmiting the same. In serial_Rx I am returning UDR so I have used it in main.Is it wrong?

Comment: It is not generating error but serial_Rx will work without UDR in the paramlist because UDR is a register of the uC, you can reach it from anywhere in your code without passing it as an argument. The real problem is what I have mentioned first. You are using a char array, length of 10 and you put the received char to the last position, the first nine remains empty. After that, you send the whole array to hyperterminal, but you should send the last one only because the others are empty. You need a function that sends only one char and with that you can send to the last char of your array.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Ok i got your point. If I do it like this: data= Serial_Rx(UDR). and then print this data, is this thing correct?

Comment: Oh and I have almost forget. `Data` is an array of chars, 10 long. So it has 10 slots, from 0 to 9. So it is wrong to use `data[10] = serial_RX();` because index 10 means slot 11 which is do not exists and you are overindexing the array. Here is a tutorial about [Arrays in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm).

Comment: If you do like this before the while cycle: `char data;` instead of `char data[10];` then it's OK to use `data = Serial_Rx(UDR)`. I do not have much time now, but I will try to give a detailed answer later.

Comment: And you will need an RX function that takes a `char` as a parameter instead of `char*`. Like: `void serial_put_c(char data){UDR=data; while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE)));}`

Comment: I have changed the code according to you but still I am not receving OK response from GSM

Comment: Make a function like in my previous comment, because now your `serial_TX` function takes an invalid type as argument, it expects `char*` but now you are passing it a `char`.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I didnt get it

Comment: I have made the changes but still not getting output

Comment: Remove the `_ms_delay(500)` and the `_ms_delay(2000)` from your code. The GSM module answers immediately but you wait 2.5 seconds before receiving the answer so you are missing it.

Comment: I have done that. Command is running because I am getting a call but nothing is displayed on hyper terminal

Comment: Okey, I missed another thing in your code which I should have checked for first, sorry for that. The UART receiver is not enabled in the UCSRB register, `UCSRB |= (1<<TXEN) | (1<<RXEN);`

Comment: Oh i am sorry for that because I have made the changes but forgot to update it here.Now I have updated it. Well I am receiving the data on my hyperterminal now I want to put some if condition on received data like if OK received then do this thing. But the problem is I am reciving a lot of data so I am confused how can I search for that string. I am attaching a pic of my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your receiver code still has a mistake in it.

```
for(int j=0;j<=100;j++)
{
    data[j] = serial_Rx();
    uart_put(data[j]);  
}
```

In this loop you are still overindexing the `data` array, which is only a size of 2. You should increase its size to 101 to match your `for` loop. Probably a smaller value will be sufficient too, but the size of the array should match the `for` loop.
As I see on hyperterminal, Local Echo is disabled on your module so it will reply to most of the commands with `"\r\nOK\r\n"` or `"\r\nERROR\r\n"`. (With Local Echo enabled it would return the command too). So the longest message that you could receive is the error message which is 9 characters long.

```
char data[10];       //9 for data 1 for terminating null character
```

---

```
for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
{
    data[j] = serial_Rx();
}
data[9] = '\0';     // close string with a terminating null character
```

Now, the response is presented in the array as a proper string. It is ready to be processed either by your own functions or by the standard C String library (`#include <string.h>`).
Or you can still send the whole string to hyperterminal as well `serial_Tx(data)`.

Process the result of the previous code with [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) function of string.h

```
    if(strstr(data,"OK") != NULL)
    {
        // it contains "OK"
        // do stuff
    }
```

---

More accurate way to receive serial data is to **enable UART receive complete interrupts** by setting `RXCIE` bit in the `UCSRB` register: `UCSRB |= (1<<RXCIE);`
If you look at the possible responses, the effective information is enclosed between a `'\n'` and a `'\r'` characters which makes excellent start and end conditions when parsing the GSM's response in the interrupt service routine.

The complete code is the following:

```
void serial_Init()
{
    UCSRB |= (1<<TXEN)|(1<<RXEN)|(1<<RXCIE);    // enable receive interrupts
    UCSRC |= (1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<URSEL);
    UBRRL = 51;
}

void serial_Tx(char *str)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0;str[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        UDR=str[i];
        while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE)));
    }
}

char serial_Rx()
{
    while(!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)));
    return UDR;
}

void uart_put(char data)
{
    UDR=data;
    while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE)));
}

///////////////////////////////////
// global variables for UART rx
///////////////////////////////////
int buffer_index = 0, started = 0;
unsigned char buffer[250];
unsigned char k;

ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{
    k = UDR;

    if(k == '\r' && started == 1)  // stop if is has already started and "\r" received
    {
        started = 2;               // finished, ready for further processing
        buffer[buffer_index] = '\0';            // terminate string
    }                              
    else if(started == 1)          // if started save data
    {                              
        buffer[buffer_index++] = k;             
    }                              
    else if(k == '\n')             // start saving data at first "\n"
    {                              
        started = 1;               // set process started
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRA = 0x00;
    DDRC = 0xFF;
    PORTA = 0xFF;
    serial_Init();
    sei();

    while(1)
    {
        if(PINA==0xFE)
        {
            buffer_index = 0;
            started = 0;
            serial_Tx("ATD<number>;\r\n");
        }

        if(started == 2)        // check if rx is finished
        {
            // check if OK
            serial_Tx(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

ISR explanation:

So the structure of the messages we are expecting is the following: `<\r><\n><data><\r><\n>`. Based on this, we want to start saving the incoming data after the first `\n` was detected and keep it up until we reach a `\r`.
 
Now the roles of the used variables:

- `k` is a temporary variable into which the received chars are loaded, then we can check if it is a `\n`, `\r` or data char and handle accordingly.
- `started` is for tracking the different phases:
  `started = 0` means, we did not receive the first `\n` so far, so we keep waiting (`else if(k == '\n')` branch ). Once a `\n` arrives we set it to `1` indicating that we can start loading the received chars (`k`) into our array.
  `started = 1` means that the start condition has been fulfilled, data can be stored in the array.
  `started = 2` when the processing has been started, so if the previous value was `1` and we received a `\r` (`if(k == '\r' && started == 1)` branch). Value `2` stops the loading of the array and indicates to the main function that the complete data is presented in the array.

I have a GSM module connected to an AVR too, so I tested the code of the ISR and get the following result:

[image]

This way `data` will contain `"OK"` or `"ERROR"`.

Comment: Hey first of all thanks for this great info. But unfortunately i didnt receive any call on my number.I am just receiving a series of AT<number> on terminal. Can you explain what the ISR is doing actually and what are the  roles of variable started and k? Thanks

Comment: one thing also. In this if(strstr(data,"OK") != NULL), I am using an led  and it gets turn on when it found OK. But what I have done I have used it for ERROR also like if(strstr(data,"ERROR") != NULL) and I have made some changes in AT<number> command so that is gives error but then led dosent turn on

Comment: I have edited the answer and added an explanation about the ISR, I hope it is not confusing. You can try to increase the size off the array because maybe you receive more `\r\n` and there is not enough room for "ERROR". On the other hand if the `if(strstr(data,"OK") != NULL)` works then add an `else` branch, since you could receive "ERROR" or "OK" if it is not "OK" then "ERROR".

Comment: Yes  i have made else branch for ERROR and its working. But I am not using your interrupt program. I am using general way of programming and its working. Now I need to read the msg coming from sim900 and need to change the number on which I am calling. So to do this, is it compulsory to use interrupts or it can be done normally. Please help.!

Comment: It is not necessary to use interrupts you can get along wihtout them. I just found that from my experiences that with interrupts it is more reliable. I do not think you have more errors in the communication so for your further problems a new question should be opened.

Comment: Can you help me with reading msg from GSM and changing number to call. Please

Comment: I think I gave answer to this question, the communication is working. The handling of the information is another question, I showed here string processing too. So you should try it yourself, there are plenty of resources on the web about string processing, that is what you need basically. And If you get stuck again you can ask a new question on this site. There is no place here for discussing new problems.

Comment: I hope you understand that this post became a bit too long thus hard for someone else to catch up or read through, and we moved on in the subject too. Anyway you can learn more if you try it yourself first. I will gladly help again (if i can) if you have a new question and show what you have tried.

Comment: No problem I understand, If i get a problem, i'll need your help. By the way which software you are using for checking output

Comment: I am using a this kind of [logic analyzer](https://www.saleae.com/). And sorry but I do not have experience with speakers and mics, my module do not have audio channel.

Comment: OK thanks for logic analyzer, and I have connected my headphones to the module and audio is coming.

Comment: Hey I am facing a problem, pls have a look at my new question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182278/error-getting-data-from-gsm-sim900

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26388/discussion-between-bence-kaulics-and-anna-carolina).

Comment: you have not included sei();. You are using UDR1 instead of UDR and USART_RX_vect instead of USART_RXC_vect

Comment: Yes, sorry my controller has two UART (UDR0, and UDR1 exists at me) and forgot to modfiy that row to fit your avr. And sei(), yes I should have told that, my main had it only I forgot to add here, I will fix it right away.