# Error getting data from GSM SIM900

Tags: c, gsm, sim900

I am interfacing with GSM SIM900. I wrote a program so that I can read the SMS in SIM900. I have made a function to transmit and receive. Whenever msg comes, GSM responds with `+CMT` along with slot number.I am trying to extract that slot number which is in digits, but I am getting garbage values

Here is the code:

```
while(1)
{
    if (serial_Rx() != NULL) // SOMETHING PRESENT TO BE READ
    {
        serial_Tx("done"); // print done 
        PORTC = 0x01; // turn on led
        for (int i=0;i<=14;i++)
        {
            data[i] = serial_Rx(); //storing received in data

            if(isdigit(data[i]))
            {
                serial_Tx("enter");
                PORTC = 0x02;
                data1[i] = data[i];
                serial_Tx(data1[i]);
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

Transmit and receive funstions:

```
void serial_Tx(char *str)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0;str[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        UDR=str[i];
        while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE)));
    }
}

char serial_Rx()
{
    //Wait untill a data is available
    while(!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)))
    {
         //Do nothing
    }

    //Now USART has got data from host and is available is buffer
    return UDR;
}

void uart_put(char data)
{
    UDR=data;
    while(!(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE)));
}
```

Hyperterminal:

[image]

Comment: If I remeber correctly your `serial_TX` functions expects a string (`char*`) as param but I suppose `k` is a single `char` variable, try with the `uart_put` function. You should have got a warning about this when you have built the code.

Comment: @BenceKaulics  Hey I have made few changes in the code. I have removed the second for loop and included the isdigit function in first loop. I am getting enter on output that means control is entering my isdigit function and has found that digit but serial_Tx(data1[i]) is not running. Can you tell me whats wrong in this.?

Comment: You get the "enter" but nothing else?

Comment: @BenceKaulics yeah and even i checked it further by putting it in a if condition like if (data[i] >=5) {serial_Tx("match");else (serial_Tx("NO MATCH"), so I was getting match on output. I used >=5 because I didnt know the exact number and I assumed it to be greater than 5 because i know it may be 7 or 8

Comment: Okey so you should definetly read about Strings, chars, and char array, char pointers in C. `Serial_TX` is for sending a string like "enter" or "match" but `k` and `data[i]` is a single char like 'a', 'b', 'c'. Try with `uart_put(data[i])`.

Comment: @BenceKaulics yes i read about strings and thnks to you for motivating me. Well I have used Uart_Put also but not getting data. For the change i used uart_put to transmit something else like only 'T' and its working but not for data[i]. I have attached my output

Comment: @BenceKaulics Hey I am getting the data properly but it is like 18181818181 where it should be 18 only. is this becuase of loops i am using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26389/discussion-between-bence-kaulics-and-anna-carolina).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the following function call is wrong:

```
serial_Tx(data1[i]);
```

Because `data1[i]` has a type of `char` but `void serial_Tx(char *str)` expects a `char*`, this function is for sending strings, not single characters. This way it causes runtime error, hence you won't get the expected output.

Though, it won't generate a compilation error, but the compiler will give a warning like this:

[image]

It is recommended to check and fix these warnings, because as you could see they could cause troubles in runtime.

So, replace the function above with the `void uart_put(char data)` function, like:

```
uart_put(data[i]);
```

and it will work.

Comment: it keep on showing the same value untill I press the reset switch. After reset, it shows new updated value, is it because the data in data1 is not getting cleared?